Build tab system navigation like web browser
I want to build a tab system similar to web browser in Flutter. At the start of the app, we can only a home tab, on which we can open new tabs. These tabs can be then deleted, like web browser tabs.
This video of my current work will explain it better than words :
https://youtu.be/ShYSMZ7uxJw
Pictures :


You can find the code here : https://github.com/dleurs/web_tab_nav
However, this code is a bit tricky to maintain because there is the navigation list of all possible routes => widgets, defined in MaterialApp.Router._routers, and a list of current visible widgets in TabBar and TabView (inside TabNavCubit/State), which is not the same.
Also, with this solution it seems impossible to create two tabs / two instances of the same route. We will have a key issue, the tabs will have a shared instance (scrolling down on first tab "List" with also scroll down on the second tab "List").
Do you have any idea on how to solve these ? Should I drop GoRouter and try to do that with vanilla Navigator 2.0 ? Or another package ?

Are you sure Router and Navigator (no matter the package) are the way to go for your need? i.e, do you need the deeplink benefits, do you want a version where people can type in url and the tab will open?
Also, I understand there could be a virtually-infinite number of tabs (like web browser), so to me the named routes does not seems to fit.
You can look at state management. Not sure the equivalent in BloC, but Riverpod has the Family concept. As per ChatGPT, in BloC this is just passing parameters in the Cubit's constructor.
If you assign an id to each tab, in Riverpod you can create a Provider.family that will be based on this id, and therefore provide tab-related data. The Tab system would be a simple "selectedTab" provider.
Just for reference fi you are not attached to BloC, see Riverpod's Family concept:
https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/modifiers/family

Thank you for your answer. Yeah it seems unified navigation system seems complicated for this project
